# Matching points on a straight line

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Given $n$ points P red and blue on a straight line, we want find all pairs of points $(p_i,p_j)$ that such that have different color and no point between theme. Suppose number of those pairs are $k$ how we can use divide and pruning to obtain an algorithm with runtime $O(n\log k)$?

I read this post [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/138808/finding-all-pairs-of-points-with-no-point-in-between.) and this paper http://www.cccg.ca/proceedings/2005/50.pdf can i use this paper to to find out an idea for my problem?

Any helpful hint be appreciated.

Comment: How long/order will take ordering the points?

Comment: It take $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: In $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time, we can rotate and translate the line such that all points are on the positive $x$-axis with the left-most point being $(0, 0)$.